# How can I animate the transparency of a image texture ontop of another image texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

Here are two photos of what the effect that I want. I want to be able to have a slider that will change the opaqueness of the "hi" and I want to be able to animate it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply the "top" texture's Alpha by a value between 0 and 1 before feeding it into the Mix node's Fac. Use a Math node (Add > Converter > Math) to multiply. 0 will let the "bottom" texture through; 1 lets through the "top".

[image: Overlay transparency varying]